# Does this code has logic errors?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am a newbie,please be gentle!I copied the code from a book:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int alarm_fired = 0;

void ding(int sig)
{
    alarm_fired = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;

    printf("alarm application starting\n");

    pid = fork();

    switch(pid)
    {
        case -1:
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0:
            sleep(5);
            kill(getpid(), SIGALRM);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    printf("waiting for alarm to go off\n");
    (void) signal(SIGALRM, ding);

    pause();
    if (alarm_fired)
        printf("Ding!\n");

    printf("done\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

As the author had written:

> `ding`,simulates an alarm clock.the child process wait for five
>   seconds before sending a `SIGALRM` signal to its parent.

---

I tried the code above,but it has no response after printing `alarm application starting`

`waiting for alarm to go off`.So I am suspecting that the code has logic error.The line `kill(getpid(), SIGALRM);` may be wrong.Am i right?

Comment: "it doesn't work" - what actually happens?

Comment: @Joe I have edited the question,I am sorry.

Comment: goto [code_review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com);

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot to mention.. [__do not use `signal()` function__](http://lazarenko.me/2013/01/15/how-not-to-write-a-signal-handler/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, the line

```
kill(getpid(), SIGALRM);
```

is wrong if the child is to send a signal to it's parent. As it is, it's trying to send a signal to himself, as he is passing his own pid by `getpid()` (get process id).

You should use `getppid()` (get parent process id) so you can send the message to the parent process, like this:

```
kill(getppid(), SIGALRM);
```

Comment: The code also has a race condition: if the parent somehow got blocked from executing for a long time after the fork, the signal handler would not be set before the signal arrives. To do this robustly, you need to either set the signal handler before calling fork, or if you don't want the signal disposition to be changed in the child, block the signal before forking and only unblock it in the parent after setting the handler (unblocking immediately in the child is fine).

Comment: @R.. Yes,the book mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGALRM);
```

is executed by the child and is sending the alarm signal to itself.

This line:

```
signal(SIGALRM, ding);
```

Is the parent setting up a signal handler for the alarm signal

And this line is waiting for the signal:

```
pause();
```

You need the child to send the signal to the parent not itself and then all the dominoes will fall.